# Weird output in tabular environment

Tags: tables, errors

I created a table and I didn't use `\\` in the last line before the final `\hline` (which I know is wrong) and in the last cell with its contents was also a word "height". Where did that word come from? And why?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
1 & 2\\
\hline
3 & 4\\
\hline
5 & 6
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This comes from [the definition of `\hline`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/h3ZLA.png) (from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx). However, the result is because of the error.

Comment: I meant it is wrong not to use it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When TeX generates an error then (if you do not stop at that point, and let it carry on) it makes an essentially arbitrary "correction" that is designed to get itself unstuck and allow it to process the rest of the document, to speed up finding later errors compared to just fixing one error and then re-running. So the real output from TeX in this case is

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.12 \hline
```

which is fixed by putting `\\` before the `\hline`. Any PDF that is produced after an error should only be viewed as a possible debugging aid, you shouldn't consider any output to be "weird". The PDF output is essentially arbitrary, in this case `\noalign` and `\hrule` were ignored in this context (after the error) so `\@height` which expands to `height` wasn't taken as a parameter of `\hrule` and instead got typeset.

---

Every TeX primitive has a "correction" behaviour built in if it is used in an error situation, this is not under the control of macros such as LaTeX.

Here `\noalign` was not at the start of a table row, after error it is ignored.

This means that `\noalign` did not start vertical mode so the `\hrule` generates an error. As you are in an `l` column you are in inner horizontal mode so in this case the `\hrule` error correction is to do nothing, so then `height` gets typeset. Had you been in  a `p` column you would have been in outer horizontal mode and there the correction is different `\hrule` would have started a new paragraph with the last column cell and then drawn a rule just over that cell, and no `height` would be typeset. (Try changing `|l|l|` to `|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|` in your example)

So what is actually typeset after an error is essentially just arbitrary rubbish as TeX inserts or ignores whatever tokens it needs to get back into an error free situation. So the only useful question to ask about such a pdf is where the rubbish appears as that is a debugging aid pointing what to fix in the source. There are no real justifications for any particular text that is typeset or disappears or gets set in math mode or any other thing TeX does to get itself back on track.

Comment: Thank you I inderstand now why I got that "height". But I didn't quite understand the rest of your comment.

Comment: @Adam which bit? I could clarify, perhaps:-)

Comment: When you said that if you don't correct an error it makes an arbitrary correction. How is that possible? What rule it uses to correct the mistake? And also the bit you said about the PDF that is like a debugging aid.

Comment: @Adam too long for a comment so I added some notes to the answer